# How to read Hive table with column with JSON strings?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table column (Json_String String) it has some 1000 rows, Where each row is a Json of same structure. I am trying read  the json in to Dataframe as below

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("select Json_String from json_table")
```

but it is throwing up the below exception

```
java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
```

is there any way to read all the rows in to dataframe  as we do with Json files using wild card

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/*.json")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is to read the Hive table as usual and transform the JSON column using [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **from_json(e: Column, schema: StructType): Column** Parses a column containing a JSON string into a StructType with the specified schema. Returns null, in the case of an unparseable string.

Given you use `sqlContext` in your code, I'm afraid that you use Spark < 2.1.0 which then does not offer `from_json` (which was added in 2.1.0).

The solution then is to use a custom user-defined function (UDF) to do the parsing yourself.

> val df = sqlContext.read.json("select Json_String from json_table")

The above won't work since [json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@json(path:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) operator expects a path or paths to JSON files on disk (not as a result of executing a query against a Hive table).

> **json(paths: String*): DataFrame** Loads a JSON file (JSON Lines text format or newline-delimited JSON) and returns the result as a DataFrame.

Comment: do you know if as of today we still need to do the parsing manually in Spark 1.6.x?

Comment: So basically as far as you remember , to parse JSON in 1.6.x we need to build a custom parser?

Comment: I think so. I'd however ask a question at stackoverflow to know better.